# Invoking mysql CLI command with QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

So i'm trying to write various commands in a command line externally from my main application. In this instance it's to create a database table in mysql.

So far this is my current implementation:

```
        QString program = "cmd.exe";   // Using command line

        QStringList arguments;
        arguments <<"/c" << "cd" << "C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB 10.4\\bin" ;   // Completes first command

        QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess();
        myProcess->setWorkingDirectory("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32");
        myProcess->start(program, arguments);

        myProcess->waitForStarted(-1);
        qDebug("Passed Started");

        int test = myProcess->state();
        qDebug() <<"State:  "<< myProcess->state();

        myProcess->write("mysql -u root -p \n");
        myProcess->waitForReadyRead();

        myProcess->write("password \n");
        myProcess->waitForReadyRead();
      
        myProcess->write("CREATE DATABASE database; \n");
        myProcess->waitForReadyRead();      
 
        qDebug () << " Ok " << myProcess->readAllStandardOutput() << myProcess->readAllStandardError();

        myProcess->waitForFinished(-1);
```

When running this no database is created but when I write the command line arguments into the command line itself it works. What am I missing in terms of implementation for QProcess? How do I know if each line i'm writing is being accepted by the command line ect?

Update 1:
I've changed the arguments to this:

```
arguments <<"/k" << "C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.4\bin\mysql.exe" << "--defaults-file=C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.4\data\my.ini -u root -p";
```

Still having issues of not having it complete the creation of the database however.

Comment: Why create a shell to run your program? Why not run `C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.4\bin\mysql` directly? Or why not use the mysql client library for this? You seem to be taking the very long way round.

Comment: @Botje What i want is my main program to create a database on execution if it doesn't exist already. Therefore every time my main program is run it will check to see if the database exists and if not to create it. That's the reason why i want to use QProcess to do this externally.

Comment: Sure, if the rest of your program does not do any database transactions at all ... Did you also consider my first two questions? Invoking `mysql` directly will remove one layer of possible failures.

Comment: I'm not sure you can pipe input to cmd like that, even if you can the shell will just execute your cd command and exit without waiting for additional commands. As above why not just use qt's mysql support, it'll be much simpler

Comment: @AlanBirtles So the scenario is my main application requires a database to exist to run. So i'm creating a class to detect whether it exists and if it doesnt to create the database before the main application is reached. How else do you propose doing this? All i found was QProcess as the way forward but would love any alternatives.

Comment: Why not simply make use of [Qt's database APIs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-connecting.html)?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Been looking into it but struggling to understand how to do the whole creating a new user (with full permissions) and in that user a new database via QSqlDatabase if it doesn't exist already

Comment: @G.M. See above^

Comment: You should be able to execute exactly the same queries as you do on the command line